# i want to animate button then change the value of it, but couldnt in android

Tags: android, animation

i want to animate button(ie; rotation, translation) then change the text of a button. unfortunately, it always first changes the text of the button then do the animation.

How can I achieve my goal?

Pls help me

my code is like this;

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

                    Animation anim1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, 500, 750);
                    anim1.setDuration(3000);
                    anim1.setFillAfter(true);
                    set.addAnimation(anim1);

                    Animation anim2 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, 1024, 824);
                    anim2.setDuration(3000);
                    anim2.setFillAfter(true);
                    set.addAnimation(anim2);

                    anim2.setStartOffset(3000);

                    first.clearAnimation();
                    set.setFillAfter(true);
                    first.startAnimation(set);      

                    numbers[0]=min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code starts the animation but is not blocking : once the animation is started, the program goes on.

You could try getting an handler and post the change text event at the right time :

```
Handler mHandler=new Handler();
Runnable lRunnable =new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
    //Your change text code                       
    }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(lRunnable , 3000); // Or any other duration so you have the right effect
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to add an AnimationListener to the animation, or if you are on JB use the view property animators and the `withEndAction()` method. You should avoid the old animation framework if possible. It doesn't actually change the properties, it just draw the view with a transformation.

```
set.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd() {
        // ...
    }

    public void onAnimationStart() {
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat() {
    }
}
```

But I recommend the view property animations if you can use them. They are much better to work with.